# Coceptual doubt about product sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

If we have two measurable spaces $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B}, \nu)$, and $\mathcal{S}=\{A \times B |A \in \mathcal{A},B \in \mathcal{B} \}$

Then it is clear that $\mathcal{S}$ is a semi-algebra and the product sigma algebra is given by $$\mathcal{F}=\sigma(\mathcal{S})$$

My question is that theorem 1.71 in Richard Durett's book on Probability theory and examples says that

1.71: There is a unique measure $(\mu \times \nu)$ on $\mathcal{F}$ with $(\mu \times \nu) (A \times B)=\mu(A) \nu (B)$

I am a bit confused if  the sets $A,B$ here refer to generic elements of $\mathcal{S} \text{ or } \mathcal{F}$

According to me since $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(\mathcal{S})$, there should be elements in $\mathcal{F}$ which do are not of the form $A \times B $ where $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and  $B \in \mathcal{B}$

Am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A,B$ here are supposed to refer to generic sets in $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$ respectively.  That is, $A \subset X$ and $B \subset Y$.

The theorem says that among the many possible measures one could put on $\mathcal{F}$, there is one which we may denote $\mu \times \nu$ that has the property that, for sets of the form $A \times B$ (that is, sets in $\mathcal{S}$), we have $(\mu \times \nu)(A \times B) = \mu(A) \nu(B)$.  There certainly are sets in $\mathcal{F}$ which are not of the form $A \times B$, but the theorem doesn't say anything explicit about what measure $\mu \times \nu$ might assign to such a set.  (However, in many cases it will be possible to work it out, using the fact that $\mu \times \nu$ is countably additive.)

Comment: Thanks Nate, that's what i had thought. So if I need to show that a progressive progressive process is adapted ,I cant say that any set set in the progressive sigma algebra is of the form $C=A \times B$ where $C \in  \mathcal{B}([0,t]) \otimes \mathcal{F}_t$ then $A \in $\mathcal{B}([0,t])$ and $B \in \mathcal{F}_t$

Comment: Right, the progressive sigma algebra is much richer than that.

Comment: Then how do i conclude that progressivity of a process implies adaptedness

Comment: @user3503589: Ask that as a new question.  Usually, to get from "simple" sets to more complicated ones, you use something like the monotone class theorem.